# How to display the correct 'style' related to the weight of a font?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I don't even know if it's correct to call it style, because its value is italic. Anyways, I am using Proxima Nova on my site and there's a weird thing about that font.

If I use this:

```
font-family: "Proxima Nova light";
```

It shows the image 1

If I do:

```
font-family: "Proxima Nova", light;
```

or:

```
font-family: "Proxima Nova";
font-weight: 100;
```

I get the image 2
[image: screenshots]

Why is this happening? Shouldn't the weight be related to the font 'style'?

How can I get it right without using method 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following attempts to load the font-family "Proxima Nova light":

```
font-family: "Proxima Nova light";
```

This attempts to load "Proxima Nova", and if it can't find it, a font-family called "light":

```
font-family: "Proxima Nova", light;
```

This, predictably, attempts to load "Proxima Nova", and sets the font-weight to light:

```
font-family: "Proxima Nova";
font-weight: 100;
```

A lot of font creators make different families for light, bold, italic, etc, instead of relying on the browser to alter the font itself. This is to avoid aliasing and other visual distortions as a result of running the characters through the generic algorithms of the browser, like `font-weight: 100`, `font-style: italic`, etc.